# jQuery listener target seems to break after the object is moved with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of objects that have a link inside to toggle a swap. The "next" swap algorithm appends the current object to the next object.

```
$('a.getNext').click(function() {
    var selector = 'div.foo';
    var currentObject = $(this).parents(selector).first();
    var nextObject = currentObject.nextAll(selector).first();
    nextObject.append(currentObject);
});
```

The swap happens but the link that invoked the swapping (in the "current" context) no longer works. Watching the debugger, after clicking the link again and seeing what object `currentObject` appears to be, it's empty whitespace in the browser. How can I reestablish the connection between the `click()` target and the correct "new"(?) `foo` div it lives inside?

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z863z/2/

Comment: Apologies, currentObject.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically shifting/swapping sibling objects around using jQuery. raina77ow's fiddle shows it working as it should be if that makes it any clearer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be...

```
currentObject.insertAfter(nextObject);
```

... instead of `nextObject.append(currentObject)`; check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhSeV/) for illustration (and a few streamlines as well). Your goal is to move the current container *after* the next one.

Your original code is placing the current element *inside* the next one. That's why the look-ups no longer work: the structure becomes broken.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I didn't realize append was literally appending it inside the object. That's what I get for reading the docs after being burned out from the day.